# Managed Metadata Service not in services list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to start the managed metadata service. But when I browse Sharepoint Central Administration->Application Management->Manage Services on the Server , I don't find any Managed Metadata Service in the Service list. Moreover if I try to add a Managed Metadata Service from the Application Management->Manage Service Application after clicking on New I get a drop-down to create only a BDCS not a MMS. 
I am new to SharePoint 2010. Please suggest what could be the related issue.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Foundation 2010 does not include the managed metadata service. You'll have to use SharePoint Server (Standard or Enterprise)